# Custom countif function in VBA with criteria without the worksheet application

Tags: excel, vba

I have to custom a countif function In VBA that only count positive Numbers, it may look very easy, but without using worksheet.application it is way harder. Can someone please help me? The function has to look like

```
Function Nombrespositifs( x as range)

End function
```

Answer (score 0):

`Mod` works nicely here

---

```
Option Explicit

Function COUNTEVEN(Target As Range)

Dim myCell As Range

For Each myCell In Target
    If IsNumeric(myCell) And 1 - (myCell Mod 2) Then
        COUNTEVEN = COUNTEVEN + myCell
    End If
Next myCell

End Function
```

Comment: thanks you, but I have 190 numbers in a column, some are positive and some are negatives, I have to select all the numbers in the column and my function has to tell me how many positive number it contains